# how to access a file from target URL after an XMLHttpRequest post

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to upload and save an image file to a server using an `XMLHttpRequest` POST after allowing file selection to be done on the client's side using HTML5 and java script (using an html input element).

My problem is that cannot find out how to actually get a hold of the file from the server side and save it to the server.

This is my code:

```
                    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    // Update progress bar etc
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        progressBar.style.width = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100 + "%";
        }
        else {
        // No data to calculate on
        }
        }, false);

        // File uploaded
        xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
        progressBarContainer.className += " uploaded";
        progressBar.innerHTML = "Uploaded!";
        }, false);

        xhr.open("post", "imageSave.aspx", true);

        // Set appropriate headers
                   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
           xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.fileName);
           xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.fileSize);
           xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", file.type);

           // Send the file
           xhr.send(file);
```

Comment: you should be posting the server side code, not the client side code..

problem lies in server side right ?   
I guess you should be receiving binary data which you should write into a file and name it with appropriate extension

Comment: after I Post it to imageSave.aspx I cannot find out how to save the image to a directory on the server. So this page is called by the POST command but I cannot save the file to server

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ASP/asp_inputforms.asp

I guess you want to know about how to read post variables in asp ? or you don't know how to open a file and write to it ? which part is difficult ?

Comment: thanks for the link Shrinath...i know I can retreive variables by using request.querystring but how can i retreive a file (in this case the image file)...and what am i supposed to do to save it onto the server...sry for asking something so trivial ;)

Comment: the thing is that I have never used XMLHttpRequest before and now that I need it to upload images onto the server I cannot find any help online regarding server side code...I only found help regarding client side script and XMLHttpRequest POST but after that I honestly have no idea

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the file using Request.InputStream but that won't work unless there is no other data in your XHR entry.